# KineticJS, event binding to group

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a group that has (custom) shapes as children. Added to this group is an mouseenter and mouseleave event. When the mouses enters the 'group' the event gets fired (as expected). However when the mouse hovers over another child within the group, the same event gets fired again.

Now this problem was also addressed as an [issue](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/603) on GitHub. Where the developer mentioned it would be fixed in version 5.0.0.

Currently, I'm using  and am still experiencing this behaviour. See http://jsfiddle.net/LwRnj/45/

Now on the other hand, I have read that adding events to a group will cause interference with its children (as what I'm experiencing). To prevent this, one should use the listening parameter of the group and/or its shapes (i.e. `shape.listening = false`) to prevent this interference

Can someone confirm that using the listening setter is indeed the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting the listening property seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/LwRnj/46/. It seems that setting this property makes the shape 'invisible' to any event handler. When binding the events to the Rect instead of the Group, it's also working: http://jsfiddle.net/LwRnj/47/

Comment: It does leave me wondering why this behaviour does not apply to issue posted on GitHub. This http://jsfiddle.net/LwRnj/ shows the behaviour I experience (using v4.7), but when updating to v5.0.1 the behaviour disappears and the listener only works on the group, not the items within the group.